# Google-services plugin won't found after updating android gradle plugin to 4.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

To use this version of the Android Gradle plugin, we have to update the Gradle plugin to `6.1.1` too.
But when I update that, the **google-services** plugin with the version of `4.3.3` won't found anymore (`404`)!
If you've had this issue, share your experience and how you fixed it?

Error:

> Could not find google-services-4.3.3.jar
> (com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3). Searched in the following
> locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.3/google-services-4.3.3.jar

*gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

*./gradle.properties*

```
...
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
...
```

*As you may know, android Gradle plugin added some exciting features like
using new API language (`java.util.stream`), check it out [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#4-0-0).*